# Understanding anonymous pipe ID

Tags: linux, pipe, file-descriptors

I'm currently debugging a system which has a resource leak. It seems that we have too many pipse open. When I go the my /proc/PROC_ID/fd I see the list of pipes

```
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jun 30 12:32 100 -> pipe:[39199]
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Jun 30 12:32 99 -> pipe:[39199]
```

this suggests an open pipe, with both RW ends.
When I use `lsof`, I see that there are a lot of results with this pipe ID

```
COMMAND    PID  TID           USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
myapp      7209                root   99r     FIFO                0,8       0t0      39199 pipe
myapp      7209                root  100w     FIFO                0,8       0t0      39199 pipe
myapp      7209 7210           root   99r     FIFO                0,8       0t0      39199 pipe
myapp      7209 7210           root  100w     FIFO                0,8       0t0      39199 pipe
myapp      7209 7211           root   99r     FIFO                0,8       0t0      39199 pipe
myapp      7209 7211           root  100w     FIFO                0,8       0t0      39199 pipe
myapp      7209 7212           root   99r     FIFO                0,8       0t0      39199 pipe
...
```

so there are several threads using the pipes. Now, I need some help interpreting this info

1. What is the ID next to the pipe (in `ls`)? Can I get it from the call to pipe() somehow?
2. why does the type in `lsof` is FIFO and not PIPE? I checked http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html and there is a separate type for it. Did I get it wrong? I'm on RHEL 7.2
   UPDATE to be more clear on the second question - judging by the `pipe:[<number>]` output of the `ls`, the object looks like an anonymous pipe. However, the `lsof` type is FIFO and not PIPE. I dont understand how these refer to the same object.

cheers

Comment: Pipe Vs FIFO: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipes-and-FIFOs.html

Answer (score 1):

For question 1 :

According to [Debugging IPC with Shell Commands](https://cdn.ttgtmedia.com/searchEnterpriseLinux/downloads/Linux_Toolbox.pdf) (see §8.7.1), `39199` in `pipe:[39199]` is an inode number.
Unlike "regular" files stored on physical devices, such inode numbers don't relate to actual files as they belong to virtual filesystems (see §8.8).

As far as I understand it, the point of these inodes is not "what the inode xxxx refers to", but rather that processes sharing inodes are actually communicating with each other. Such processes may be output by :

```
lsof | grep <inodeNumber>
```